# Significant new developments since rejected paper -- do I still try to publish the original one?

Tags: publications, arxiv, rejection, publishability

I'm working on a topic in engineering and submit a paper to a journal about 6 months ago (which I also posted on ArXiV).  The paper was recently rejected.  Since the original submission, I've made significant progress on the problem, and I've written that progress and additional developments, into another paper which I plan to submit to a conference at the end of the month.  I had originally been planning to cite the earlier paper, but in fact a lot of what was in the original paper is made essentially obsolete by my new developments.

To try to summarize the situation: paper 1 does "X and Y", is on ArXiV, and was rejected by a journal.  Paper 2 does "X++ and Z", and I'm planning to submit this to a conference soon.  Content "Y" is not significant enough to be it's own paper, but contains some important information that needs to be referred to in order for "Z" to make sense.

Should I still try to publish the original paper somewhere?  Should I combine that paper with the new developments and publish that (i.e., publish "X++, Y, and Z")?  Or, should I just leave the original one standing on ArXiV and forget about getting it through peer review?

Comment: Why was it rejected?

Comment: The reviewers wanted to see some extra content about "W" (some simulations of sensitivity to certain inputs) which we had thought seemed out of scope, that some of the content was superfluous (which I agree with now), that the conclusions were not quite what the journal wants (this is pretty fair), and that we didn't make enough contribution over and above a paper we took inspiration from (which I think is inaccurate, our formulation is similar, but not identical, and our analysis and conclusions are much stronger).

Comment: Both options can be good. It really depends on the paper(s) and the preferences of yourself and your coauthors.

Comment: Are you in an area where conferences are a publication venue?  Are conference papers considered real papers, or is it expected that the papers presented at conferences will be submitted (perhaps with further work) to journals and the journal version will be the real publication?

Comment: Thanks for this feedback -- It is my impression that good conference publications are considered "real" papers, but I think my advisor strongly prefers that we publish in journals.  Often, he publishes early work in a conference, then a much longer and expanded version in a journal.

Comment: Will the paper be too rambling if you include the parts of X and Y relevant to X++ and Z in your new paper? They might make sense to bundle together even if you leave some parts of X and Y to remain only on arxiv.

Comment: That is the path I'm leaning towards, it makes sense to put a lot of it together and definitely makes for a better paper.  I think my main concern, which I didn't articulate in the original question, is if it's okay to leave the arxiv paper standing and have a lot of repetition from that version (e.g. the introduction and literature review will be very similar) in another published paper.

i.e., is it bad to have "dangling" arxiv papers?  It seems a bit unavoidable if I post to arxiv before getting it accepted, which is the point of arxiv in the first place right?

Comment: It's fine to leave dangling papers on arxiv.  You should put a comment in the "Comments" metadata for both papers on arxiv.